# How do I make spring security to authorize a user type to access only certain controller functions?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Im using spring security for authorization.

Well it works fine but the matter is for a request pattern `/user/**` I'd want some usertype to just read the data and some others to read and change the data.

I added `@Secured(value={"ADMIN"})` annotation before specific controller functions but it seems to have no effect and every usertype that has access to `/user/**` can do every task within it.

Any help??

Comment: Show your Spring Security configuration.

Answer (score 1):

To use method-level security in your application make sure you've **enabled** it.

In your security configuration class you need to add [`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableGlobalMethodSecurity.html) annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class YourSecurityConfig {}
```

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html).